# How do you create a report in Google Analytics that displays a list of all events?

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

I'm looking to create a report that lists out every event captured in Google Analytics with the following columns:

- Event Category
- Event Action
- Event Label
- Event Value

Is this feasible through some tweaking of the default views or a custom report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a Custom Report. Just create a flat table report with dimensions and metrics like so:

[image]